# Browser converting spaces to html attributes of json string

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am creating dynamic table rows and `tds` in it. In the last td I need to have anchor tags with `onclick` event passing some data as json string. It is working fine unless I give space to any value of json string, it converts all remaining data to html attributes after space.
I am using `JSON.stringify(data)` but feels like it didn't convert it to real string. I don't know!

The last td of table rows in html just work fine even if there are spaces in values as keys and values are form data. I am using `echo json_encode` in onclick function

```html
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="a{{$i}}" 
onclick='show_detail_modal(JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($data);?>))' 
<i class="far fa-eye fa-sm"></i>
</a>
```

```js
var str_data = JSON.stringify(data);
var submit_type_text = $(form).find('button[type=submit]').text();
var tbl_id = main_form_id.replace('tabform', '')+'table';
var last_tr = $('#'+tbl_id).children('tbody').children('tr:last');
var last_tr_no_plus_one = parseInt($(last_tr).children('td:first').text())+1;
var actions = '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="a'+last_tr_no_plus_one
+'"onclick=show_detail_modal('+str_data+') style="color: inherit;"><i class="far fa-eye fa-sm"></i></a>&nbsp;';
var last_td_of_last_tr = actions;     
var inputs = $(form).find('.input');

var tr_and_tds = '<tr>';
    tr_and_tds += '<td>'+last_tr_no_plus_one+'</td>';

    $.each(inputs, function(a, b){
        tr_and_tds += '<td>'+$(b).val()+'</td>';                
    });
    
    tr_and_tds += '<td>';
    tr_and_tds += last_td_of_last_tr;
    tr_and_tds += '</td>';
    tr_and_tds += '</tr>';
    $('#'+tbl_id).append(tr_and_tds);
```

[image]

Notice after the space in New York it converts rest of the data to attributes

Comment: The problem starts way sooner. You cannot enclose the value of an attribute in `"` when the value also uses `"` (like it is the case in JSON)

Comment: _"The last td of table rows in html just work fine"_ - because you use a single qoute `'` for the value of the attribute

Comment: Don't create the elements by concatenating strings. Use DOM methods like `document.createElement` and then `setAttribute()`

Comment: @mohsinali actually you are missing to close `a` tags `>` bracket .    onclick='show_detail_modal(JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($data);?>))'`>` .. </a>

Comment: that is just by mistake during copy and paste into this site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put single quotes around the `onclick` attribute, since the JSON uses double quotes. Just like you do in the PHP code.

Use template literals to make it easier to substitute variables into strings.

```
var actions = `<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="a${last_tr_no_plus_one}" onclick='show_detail_modal(JSON.stringify(${str_data}))' style="color: inherit;"><i class="far fa-eye fa-sm"></i></a>&nbsp;`;
```

Note that this will not work if `str_data` contains single quotes.

Comment: Is it bad question or something  :(

Comment: ok never mind, any way thank you mate for your help

Comment: sorry barmar I have a problem if you are there

Comment: when it's land at "show_detail_modal()" on click, it shows as json object not a string, how can I have it there as just a normal string

Comment: Try using `show_detail_modal(JSON.stringify(${str_data}))`

Comment: But why do you need to pass a string to `show_detail_modal()`? It's just going to have to parse it with `JSON.parse()`. Why not just pass the object already parsed?

Comment: already using JSON.parse there for some other purpose and just giving it to that function as it is so it works without disturbing previous logic